# How to read all the tabs url from a chrome browser using Python

Tags: python

I have a python code which reads the url of current tab and prints it.

Is there a way to find the number of open tabs in chrome so I can iterate on all tabs and get url.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(0, 200) # a random click for focusing the browser
pyautogui.press('f6')

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') # for copying the selected url
import pyperclip # pip install pyperclip required
url = pyperclip.paste()
print(url)
```

Comment: If you're doing it this way, open a new tab, then press ctrl+tab until you get to the new tab again I guess.

Comment: I want to write a code to iterate over all the tabs until it returns to first tab.

Comment: To be more specific, "open" = "use code to open" and "press ctrl+tab" = "use code to press ctrl+tab". The new tab would be something to check for when you are done iterating over tabs.